# SQL partitioning - partition by equal value

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have a task in partitioning a table `ENTRY` by column `PART_DATE` by 3-month period. In addition to this task, there is one special case in the `ENTRY`. These cases have `PART_DATE` equal to 1.1.2000 and `STATUS = 'legacy'`. Those should have its own partition. Currently, there are no other entries with that date nor are others expected, so classical approach with

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (PART_DATE) INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(3, 'MONTH'))
(
  PARTITION "LEGACY_P" VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('02.01.2000', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
)
```

will probably work. But I was wondering if there is a "proper" way to do this. Like "values from select where" kind of way. Googling so far always points me back to `VALUES LESS THAN` construct.

I'd also like to avoid subpartitioning (by range, probably by `STATUS` values) just to create this specific partition

Comment: The way you do this it the way how it should be done. I don't have any other idea to achieve it.

Comment: So are there are cases where `PART_DATE = 1.1.2000` and `STATUS != 'legacy'` ???

Comment: @APC: No, there are not. When migrating the old DB to current one, all dates older than 1/1/00 were merged on the single date an got legacy status. In theory, there could be some, but since the Entries are always logged with PART_DATE = today, unless some wild backtracking happens... there will not be any cases like that...

Comment: In which case I agree with @WernfriedDomscheit - what you have in your question is the approach to take